# Correct usage of semicolon?

Tags: semicolons

I think I understand the use of semicolons *reasonably* well, but could someone tell me if I am using it correctly here please:

> *My research focuses on pulsars; exotic remnants of dead stars.*

Thank you.

Comment: This isn't exactly my area of expertise; but I suggest using a colon. Reason: [the second clause explains the first](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/colon).

Comment: This is my area of expertise, and I can assure you that the semi-colon is the correct form of punctuation in this instance. A colon would be grammatically incorrect.

Comment: I am reminded of an old episode of *Murder She Wrote* where Jessica was able to determine that a ransom note was a phony (and who likely wrote it) because a semicolon was used *correctly*, "and hardly anyone knows how to use a semicolon correctly".

Comment: I wouldn't use a colon or semi-colon. "My research focuses on pulsars, which are exotic remnants of dead stars." Or more scientific: "My research focuses on exotic remnants of dead stars, which are called 'quasars'." Those sentences express the idea more clearly and sound less chatty.

Comment: @user128193 I was taught--in cases where a semicolon is not used to delineate a list--both sides of the semicolon must be a complete sentence, whereas a colon only requires _one_ side to be a complete sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either a **semicolon or a colon** to join **two main clauses**, *but you can only use a colon to join a main clause with a noun or phrase.*

Here's an example: "Squiggly missed only one friend: Aardvark." You couldn't use a semicolon in that sentence because **the two parts are unequal**.

I suggest:  "My research focuses on pulsars: exotic remnants of dead stars."

Or create 2 independent clauses:
"My research focuses on pulsars; They are exotic remnants of dead stars."

Comment: Good job. I agree. +1.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct usage - you are linking two independent but closely related ideas with the semicolon, such as:

> [Some people write with a word processor; others write with a pen or pencil](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html)

Comment: You really think the second clause is independent? I think it depends rather heavily on `pulsars`.